# Using contourf to plot the mapping color (z axis color coding) in Log scale?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to make a 2D map of three dimensional data. Since the amount of quantities of z axis which I would like to project and color code in 2D are very small and the peak is very important to be shown, I decided to show them in log scale. I have written this piece of code but first of all, it doesn't show contour plots properly and secondly the colorbar shrinks to the top while the numbers of each color are in their expected places.
I also want to smooth the x-y plane sufficiently but with the gaussian_filter they all shrunk.

```
ny, nx = 100, 100
nstep=8
loglvl=np.logspace(np.log10(0.0000001),np.log10(max(zp)),nstep)
bins_x=np.linspace(min(xp),max(xp),nx)
bins_y=np.linspace(min(yp),max(yp),ny)
H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(xp, yp, (bins_x,bins_y),weights=zp)
smooth=0.05
Hsmooth = scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter(H.T, smooth)
xcenters = (xedges[1:] + xedges[:-1])/2.
ycenters = (yedges[1:] + yedges[:-1])/2.
Ygrid, Xgrid = np.meshgrid(ycenters, xcenters)
extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1] ]
plt.contourf(Xgrid,Ygrid,Hsmooth,levels=loglvl,extent=extent)
plt.colorbar() 
plt.show()
```

an example of my data:

```
  xp         yp      zp
 7781.36    44.40   0.00000

 6776.45    37.61   0.00000

 3913.00    37.88   0.00000

 3884.64    34.13   0.00000

 3174.49    32.75   0.00372

 4396.89    27.54   0.03209

 3742.59    31.88   0.00287

 2590.11    22.88   0.00000

 1930.72    25.95   0.00000

 4979.53    25.87   0.00156

 3023.91    21.71   0.00340

 3411.53    23.02   0.00000

 6606.04    21.12   0.00026

 4420.83    20.72   0.00000

 3847.91    20.67   0.00008

 2911.36    19.28   0.00000

 5179.67    19.14   0.00000

 3085.58    19.02   0.00000

 4150.57    18.82   0.00000

 1417.97    19.03   0.00000

 7948.60    16.02   0.01354

 4560.82    14.73   0.00000

 4407.12    15.79   0.00021

 4767.00    13.68   0.00000

 4665.62    13.58   0.00000

 3195.62    14.71   0.01170

 3866.52    25.97   0.00000

 3448.50    13.31   0.00010

 7473.90    10.73   0.00474

 4548.85    10.82   0.00086

 1563.84    11.19   0.00006

 4171.65    10.52   0.00002

 2617.41    10.08   0.00211

 2200.51    10.28   0.00062

 1295.38    10.38   0.00811

 3172.31    9.75    0.00200

 4913.99    8.32    0.00037

 6435.21    8.40    0.00673

 3611.03    10.31   0.00000

 3795.64    48.01   0.00000

 5170.69    32.81   0.00000

 2256.22    22.38   0.00000

 4703.77    17.78   0.00059

 2845.35    10.12   0.00028

 3275.11    28.39   0.03358

 4830.32    26.12   0.00000

 7653.76    13.43   0.00003

 3419.52    13.26   0.00000

 2174.30    13.29   0.00016

 7118.04    19.40   0.00821
```

The problem of using LogNorm for contourf also exists since some of the zp numbers are zero.
In my data there are some regions which have been masked and there isn't any point there so I also like that these regions have been shown in the map adequately.
How could I get my code to work?

Comment: Could you post your example data in a way that makes it easy to copy/paste into an interpreter?

Comment: @ali_m how could I post my data here ? Is it possible to attach an ascii file to the post?

Comment: If I were you I would paste only a representative subset of the values, and I would include the whole call to `np.array`, e.g. `xp = np.array([7781.36, ..., 5179.61])`. You can break the statement in parentheses across lines for readability. If you can provide a copy/paste-able [MWE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215383/247805) you stand a *much* better chance of getting a good answer to your question!

Comment: You can also use [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or [gist](https://gist.github.com/), but it's [generally better to include all the necessary information in your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259).